# why convolution is often related with smoothing and averaging?

Tags: fourier-analysis, convolution

I'm not sure if I can discuss some less math-majored problems here(i'm not a math-majored students), I'm studying convolution in the Fourier transform, and I see a sentence that **convolution can be understood as using one function to smooth and average another function**. I don't understand **why it's smoother** (I can probably feel some of it through some cases and through some thoughts, but I'd like to get a more robust explanation), and as I think about it deeply, I come across another question: **how to define smoothness**?

I have some rough explanations of g*f, such as using a sharp centered normalized g(x), and then I can find that the highest point of f(x) will fall, and the lowest point will rise, so the slope becomes smaller, so it is more smoother. However, I always feel the explanations are not strong enough, and I hope to have a better explanation.

or may be you have some excellent materials about convolutions with smooth and average can recommend to me?

Comment: Maybe smoothing a digital image by replacing the intensity value at each pixel with a weighted average of intensity values at nearby pixels would help build some intuition.

Comment: Convolving $f$ with $g$ corresponds to pointwise multiplication of $\hat f$ with $\hat g$. If $\hat g$ has bounded support, then multiplying by $\hat g$ kills off the high frequencies in $f$. So convolving with $g$ is a “low pass filter” operation.

Comment: Well, if $g(x)=1/N$ when $x\in [-N/2,N/2],$ and $0$ otherwise, then $f*g$ really is the moving average of $f.$

Comment: The convolution of $f$ with $g$ can be thought of as a weighted sum of shifted versions of $g$. So the result is at least as smooth as $g$ is.

Comment: So, convoluting with a step function is like a linear combination of sums of translated moving averages. And we can estimate most nice functions with step functions.